# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined while trying to get users according to a User ID.

My routes and controllers looks like this :

//routes.js

```
var AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/authentication');

module.exports = function (app){
    var apiRoutes = express.Router();
    apiRoutes.get('/user/:_id', AuthenticationController.getUserById);
    app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
};
```

// controllers

```
 exports.getUserById = function (req, res, next){
        User.findById(
            {_id: req.params._id}, function(err,users){
                if (err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.status(200).json({
                    Success: true,
                    user: users
                });
            });
};
```

Below is my unit testing code for get user by ID.

//user-test.spec.js

```
describe('/GET/:_id user', () => {
    it('it should get a user by the given ID', (done) => {
        var user = new User({ email: "mjn.nilesh12@gmail.com", password: "gunners", fullname: "Nilesh Maharjan"});
        user.save((err, user) => {
            chai.request(server)
            .get('api/user/' + user._id)
            .send(user)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

// Full error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
      at user.save (test/user-test.spec.js:73:38)
      at /Users/seva/Desktop/project1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4670:16
      at /Users/seva/Desktop/project1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:250:11
      at $__save.error (node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:476:16)
      at /Users/seva/Desktop/project1/node_modules/kareem/index.js:246:48
      at next (node_modules/kareem/index.js:167:27)
      at next (node_modules/kareem/index.js:169:9)
      at Kareem.execPost (node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3)
      at _handleWrapError (node_modules/kareem/index.js:245:21)
      at _cb (node_modules/kareem/index.js:304:16)
      at /Users/seva/Desktop/project1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:329:9
      at /Users/seva/Desktop/project1/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Comment: Could you show us full error that you are getting?

Comment: I guess your `User` class is a Mongoose document? Is it correctly saved into the db?

Comment: @Ivan Vasiljevic: Here it goes, the full error. Please see above

Comment: `if (typeof req.params._id == 'undefined') return;`

Comment: Do you have connection to MongoDB in tests? I remember that I had similar issues when I didn't have connection to DB in my code. Because of that I wasn't able to persist my objects.

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic: I do have connection to MongoDB. The user gets saved to the database. However, while trying to get the information from the database, it seems user._id parameter isn't populated. Do check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860595/uncaught-assertionerror-expected-object-domain-events-to-have-stat